# Trying to stick a span tag to the bottom of the div

Tags: css

It works in  chrome , and not in ff/opera.

Demo here: http://booksnearby.in/browse_items.php . The 'location: Dhoolsiras Village, delhi' line 'hangs' in the middle. I am trying to make it stay at the bottom of its container.
For this I tried

```
Child span tag- {
bottom: -5px;
font-size: 11px;
left: 115px;
line-height: 20px;
position: absolute;
}
Parent:- element.style {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

But it doesn't work, except in chrome. Please help

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to use a table? Because your problems come from the td element's height. Tables have the worst cross browsers support out of all the html elements :)

Is it possible to change the structure to use div elements instead?

**OR** you could give the `position: relative` to your `.listtd` instead of the div (which means remove the position property from the div). This solution will do the trick.

Comment: listtd already had position:relative. BUT I also had left:115px, so the solution was to disable position:relative on div, and remove left:115px! Thanks